# how to render records in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am trying to render all the record of articles having true bookmarked. but it is showing this error :

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

Here is my code:

```
def index
  # Also we are showing all showcased articles
  if params[:bookmarked]=="true"
    @favourite=Favourite.all
    @favourite.map do |f|
      article_id = f.item_id
      @article = Article.find_by_id(article_id)
      render :json => @article
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: You're having the `render` in a loop. Are you trying to display all the articles which are bookmarked ? What is the relation b/w `favourite` and `article` ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to display all the articles which are bookmarked.favourite contains id of articles which are bookmarked.

Comment: Then in your controller, you'll have to just do `@articles = Article.where(bookmarked: true)`. This will return all the articles which are bookmarked only, and then in your view `index.html.erb`, you can use that instance variable `@articles` and do the looping.

Comment: what is the name of the column that tells an article it is bookmarked? Is it `bookmarked`? as the previous comment assumed?